# how easy to filter data by dates with uitableview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, filter

will like to know how easy to do the date change and get a new set of data for my tableview.

something like myfitnesspal app. any comments or web link to tutorial are very much appreciated.

thanks for reading

```
- (IBAction)previousDayButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self changeCurrentDayBy:-1];

    [self.drinksTableView reloadData];
}

- (IBAction)nextDayButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self changeCurrentDayBy:1];

    [self.drinksTableView reloadData];
}

- (void)changeCurrentDayBy:(NSInteger)numberOfDays
{

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make each segmented controller a new query on your data it's easy to resort a tableView. It depends on how well your data is structured. See NSFetchRequest if your data is in CoreData or the NSArray class if your data is just held in dictionaries or arrays. There are built in SDK functions that let you organize and sort your tableView array's pretty easily.

Comment: Hi Eric,

Thanks for the reply, i'm using arrays and SLQ passing a date to filter query to get my desired array. do u know of any good tutorial for it ?